# Display data as insert statements

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to move data from one database to another. 
I can use python my counterpart can't.

How can select all data from a table and save it as insert statements.
Using SQLalchemy. 
Is there a way to create a back up like this?

Comment: this is called "scripting".  look in your database's docs for that

Comment: I have 38 tables to do this to. I would rather just run a for loop on the list through the ORM.

Comment: if you want to create backup then maybe use specialized program for this - for example `mysql` has `mysqldump` which creates SQL file with `INSERT`, `CREATE`, etc.

Comment: probably with `SQLAlchemy` you will have to get all data and generate strings `INSERT` on your own.

Comment: Manually generating `INSERT` strings is going to be tricky; if you don't get it exactly right, you'll end up with SQL injection problems (when the data contains quotes or similar)...

Answer (score 1):

- As others have suggested in comments, using the database backup program (`mysqldump`, `pg_dump`, etc) is your best bet; that will make sure that the data is transferred correctly for the underlying database.
- Outputting `INSERT` statements will be risky; even the built-in SQLAlchemy facility for doing this comes with a big red warning, complete with a picture of a dragon, indicating that it can be dangerous.

  If you nevertheless need to do this, and the data is generally trusted and doesn't contain much in the way of odd types, you can use:

  1. Create (but do not execute) an [insert expression](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#coretutorial-insert-expressions) as though you were inserting the rows back into the database.
  2. Use the [`.compile()` method](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/sqlexpressions.html#how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined) with the relevant dialect parameter and `literal_binds` set to True.
  3. Manually double-check that the output is, in fact, valid for the database; as per the [warning in the SQLAlchemy FAQ](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/sqlexpressions.html#rendering-bound-parameters-inline), this method is not very dependable and may expose you to attacks if it's part of any production system.
- I wouldn't recommend formatting up `INSERT` statements by hand; you're unlikely to do a better job than SQLAlchemy...